# How can you construct a graph of $2n \geq 6$ vertices with $2k$ vertices of degree $3$, and all others degree $4$

Tags: graph-theory

Also $ 1 \leq k \leq (n-1)$
But with the restriction that the vertex of the graph can't be partitioned in sets $A_1, A_2$ such that $[A_i] = T_i$ where $T_i$ is a tree, for $i =1,2$

I know that a degree sequence $s={3,3,...,4,4}$ a pair number of 3 and 4s its graphical. But i have no idea how to construct a graph with this restriccions.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I can bring the problem down to the issue of constructing a few smaller graphs, by solving it for $2n\ge 10$. I do this by ensuring that any attempt to make a tree will result in a disconnected graph for one part, by having cycles either side of a [cut edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)). The basic (cubic) graph on $10$ nodes is this:

[image]

Now we can add edges blue-to-blue or red-to-red to make up the required number of degree-$4$ nodes. The cut-edge in green ensures you cannot extract a tree that has a node in every cycle without disconnecting the remaining nodes. This can be easily extended to larger numbers of nodes also, for example on $12$ nodes:

[image]

A variation of this arrangement also works for the case on $8$ nodes with only $2$ degree-$4$ nodes by adding a cut edge between two copies of $K_4$.

[image]

This leaves the $2$ other cases for $2n=8$ and the $2$ cases for $2n=6$ to demonstrate, for which I suspect the disconnection trick will not work in the same way.